# XPATH - how to use multiple paths

Tags: arrays, xpath

I am using xpath to retrieve the text value of some links (a) in a given element. I then push the results to an array called $tableau. Everything is working fine :) The thing is, I would like now to retrieve also the href of those links. So have both the text value and the href in my array. The other thing is, I have no idea how to do that. Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

```
$url = 'http://www.somesite.com';
$path = '.../a';
$tableau = array();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($url);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$x = $xpath->query($path);

foreach ($x as $value)
     array_push($tableau, $value->nodeValue);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hints given by javram and vireshad I manage to find the solution. See here below:

```
$url = 'http://www.somesite.com';
$path = '.../a';
$tableau = array();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($url);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$x = $xpath->query($path);

foreach ($x as $value)
     array_push($tableau, array($value->nodeValue, $value->getAttribute('href')));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use an associative array

```
 the code might look like this(not sure abt the syntax though)
 arr = [ "1" => [ "text" => "value1" , "href" => "value1"],
         "2" => [ "text" => "value2", "href" => "value2"]];
```

the xpath xpression to retrieve the href of all the anchor tags is something like this

```
  ("//a/@href");

  //     --> select a from all the descendants of the root
  a      --> select the anchor tag
  @href  --> select the href of this anchor (@ to select attributes)
```

convert this expression to equivalent PHP code

Comment: Hello vireshas. I know how to retrieve href... The thing is I would like to push both the text value (a) and the href (@href) to my array. And I don't know how to do both simultanously...

Comment: you have to use an associative array , i am not sure about the syntax but it should look something like this ["text"="value","href"="value"].. you can also try using a hash

Comment: Your idea of using associative arrays made me investigate what that is. Reading articles, I found out that multidimensional arrays might be the solution. I need some time to confirm that... Thanks vireshas :)

Comment: you are welcome marc .. i shall edit the answer to reflect your need :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach ($x as $value)
{
    array_push($tableau, $value->nodeValue, $value->getAttribute('href'));
}
```

Comment: Hello javram. Thanks for trying to help. I know how to retrieve href... My problem is I don't know how to push both the text value (a) and the href (@href) to my array (simultaneously)

Comment: An array is going to have storage for a single string at every index of the array.  If you want to store multiple values at each index of the array, than you will need an array that supports a complex type. Alternatively, you could concatenate the nodeValue and href together with a delimiter, and than store it in a single position of the array.

Comment: Based on vireshas hint, I found out that multidimensional arrays might be a solution. As I said I need some time to test that out... Thanks again to take time to try helping me.

Comment: Javram, to test your suggestion i need to make a change to my code that will take some time. Nevertheless the getAttribute('href') is a great hint. Thanks...